# Python - How to convert a string from binary to integer list?

Tags: python

I got a string like:

```
s = "\0x01\0x02\0x01\0x11"
```

And I want to get the average number of that string. I tried this:

```
sum = 0
for d in s:
    sum += int(d)
```

But it said "invalid literal for int() with base 10:'\x08'" :-(

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Do you really want that last value to be 11?

Comment: Do you mean `s = "\x01\x02\x01\x11"`?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the [struct module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).

```
>>> import struct
>>> s = '\x01\x02\x01\x11'
>>> struct.unpack('=4B', s)
(1, 2, 1, 17)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python `int()` function, the first argument is the string, the second is the base of the number.

You need to check the base, because what you posted looks like hexadecimal numbers (0x0 usually denotes a HEX number, additionally 02 is not a valid binary number).

For binary (base two):

```
num = int("0x11", 2); # num will be 3
```

For hexadecimal (base 16):

```
num = int("0x0A", 16); # num will be 10
```

To convert your string ("\0x01\0x02\0x01\0x11"):

```
numbers = [int(s, base) for s in "\\0x01\\0x02\\0x01\\0x11".split("\\") if len(s)]
```

If run with `base = 16`, outputs: `numbers = [1, 2, 1, 17]`

You can then find the average using:

```
average = sum(numbers)/len(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`ord()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) will, when given a string of length one, give you the code point of the character in that string. You should just be able to use this instead of `int()` in your code, which would look something like this:

```
sum = 0
for d in s:
    sum += ord(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
s = "\0x01\0x02\0x01\0x11"
list = s.split('\0x')
list.remove('')

sum = 0
for d in list:
    sum += int(d)

# 15
```

Comment: These numbers are normally base 16 so \0x11 is actaully 17